# jade/stylus syntax highlighting for coda

Tags: css, haml, less, pug

is it possible? I tried haml and a less one since they are similar, but no luck. Less one showed up in modes and haml one didnt even show up.

I added file type in pref window and no luck either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I created a syntax mode for jade this past week. It is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/aaronmccall/jade.mode).

I have submitted it for inclusion at the [Coding Monkeys](http://www.codingmonkeys.de/subethaedit/modes.html) site that @adam-soffer mentioned above.

It is not feature complete yet, but it is definitely very useful. I will be improving it, and I would really appreciate any feedback (via GitHub issues) that you could provide.

Comment: Hey, I've been using your jade.mode and it's working pretty nicely. Your colors are burned into my brain as to what jade code is. Thanks!

Comment: Nice!  Looking forward to using it.  Will post feedback soon.

Comment: using it now, good stuff! been using hacked version of a sass highlight, this is wayyyyy better.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a list of all the downloadable, third party Coda-compatible syntax modes:
http://www.codingmonkeys.de/subethaedit/modes.html

Unfortunately, no one has taken it upon themselves to write one for Jade.  Anyone up for the task? :)

Comment: I made a really hacked together one but it was terrible. But ended up going over to textMate after the maker of Coda dared me to. hah, so I did, and now I love textmate :X

Answer (score 0):

Coda 2 was recently released, and there is now an open source jade syntax mode for Coda 2, compliments of Aaron McCall and Tom Stoecklein. Tom also has a stylus syntax mode for Coda 2.

https://github.com/aaronmccall/jade.mode/tree/coda2_master

https://github.com/bluestrike2/stylus.mode